# superscript or subscript inside italics in org buffer does *not* change text appearance

Tags: org-mode

I was trying to write 2 raised to 3 in italics inside an `org-mode` buffer and it did not work (i.e., no visual change happens to the text in the buffer).  That is:

- The text does not change to italic
- The ^ does not disappears and the superscript letter does not become a superscript like in a word document.

I tried both:

- `/2^3/`
- `/2^{3}/`

Could you suggest a solution?

(PS: I have tried toggling `C-c C-x \`)

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  Please clarify a few points.  First, what are you trying to do?  Second, what do you expect your code to do?  Third, what does it do instead?

Comment: Works for me in both PDF and HTML export. The HMTL code is `<i>2<sup>3</sup></i>`. Org mode version 9.0.5 (release_9.0.5-288-g4caad0)

Comment: @NIck . You were right, in export it works. That was my mistake.

Comment: @Dan. Thank You. I have clarified the question.

Comment: In order to get italics, bold, etc in the emacs buffer, you have to use a font that provides italics, bold etc. Apparently, you are not using one of those. In my case, I can see the italics in the buffer. But I don't see the superscript and I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: @Nick. It was not a font problem. I found the solution (below) by trial and error.

Comment: What is the function associated to C-c C-x \?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/2^3 ./
```

1. Superscript (and subscript) requires a space after (even when {} are used).
2. Also for italics to work there should NOT be a space before the ending / . Hence the need to do a "something/"

Comment: It would help if you could update your question and your answer to explain what you are trying to do.  There's not enough information yet for other users to know what the problem is, and how this answer resolves it.

Comment: @Dan. Thank You. I have clarified the question and answer a little more. Is it clear and understandable now?

Comment: [U+200B](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) can be used instead of `.` to end italics, as it's not considered a whitespace character.

Answer (score 2):

`org-toggle-pretty-entities` doesn't prettify [standard org emphasis](https://orgmode.org/manual/Emphasis-and-monospace.html), it prettifies [LaTeX-style special symbols](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Special-symbols.html). You could use these special symbols instead to get pretty characters in `org-mode` buffers.